# How to create an array of nested components outside of the render() function in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a screen implemented as a class, with a render method. I'm trying to create a method which will return an array of `<View>` components with two `<Text>` components as children.

To distill the problem down further here, I'm just trying to figure out how to return a component nested with a child. I.e.:

```
  makeNested() {
    return <View> <Text>test</Text> </View>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.makeNested()}
    )
  }
```

Which gives me an error telling me that text needs to be rendered inside a `<Text>` component, so it doesn't seem to be parsing the inner component as a JSX object.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Try wrapping your `this.makeNested()` call with a fragment: `<>{this.makeNested()}</>`

Comment: @ehutchllew Wow that works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export default class YourScreen extends Component {
 makeNested() {
    return <View> <Text>test</Text> </View>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.makeNested}
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `this` in my question. `this.makeNested()` doesn't make a difference for me. Does this work for you?

Comment: Have you tried binding inside the function constructor? this.maskedNested = this.maskedNested.bind(this);